Spring Batch: ResultSet is closed after first chunk
We're updating Spring Batch and the Spring Boot Framework of our batch processing application (built with Spring Boot) from version 4.3.4 to 5.1.1. Previously, we used the HibernateCursorItemReader in combination with a query provider to fetch records from various tables.
In version 5.1.1 the class HibernateCursorItemReader is deprecated and marked for removal. The spring batch documentation recommends to use JpaCursorItemReader instead. We're using it like this:
@Bean
public Step processRecords(MyStepConfig stepConfig) {
  return new StepBuilder("MyStep", this.jobRepository)
      .<SourceRecord, ProcessedRecord>chunk(1000, this.platformTransactionManager)
      .reader(stepConfig.readRecords())
      .processor(stepConfig.processItems())
      .writer(stepConfig.writeItems())
      .listener(stepConfig.runListener())
      .build();
}

We've some trouble using this class because the reader aborts with the following stacktrace after the first chunk of 1000 records is read and successfully processed:
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: You can't operate on a closed ResultSet!!!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:77)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.sql.results.jdbc.internal.JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.advanceNext(JdbcValuesResultSetImpl.java:218)
    ... 62 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.sql.ResultSet.next()" because "this.inner" is null
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyResultSet.next(NewProxyResultSet.java:685)
    ... 63 common frames omitted

I assume the ResultSet is closed because the transaction for the first chunk is committed. I've read that one potential solution is to bypass the transaction managed by the transaction manager. According to this article this is done by using a separate DataSource which does not take part in transactions. I'd like to try this approach, but I've absolutely no idea how to do it with Hibernate. We don't need transactions at all, because no database records are update by our application.
The problem does not occur when using the JpaPagingItemReader but the performance of this reader is significantly worse than before.
Has anyone experienced this issue when using Spring Batch as CLI-Program with Spring Boot?
Any useful hints are appreciated.
I've tried already:

using Hibernate in read-only mode by setting the query hint org.hibernate.readOnly = true
using a different TransactionManager (ResourcelessTransactionManager

Edited:
My reader-class inherits from JpaCursorItemReader and sets the query via QueryProvider like in the following code snippet.
The Hibernate Configuration is created by aggregating connection properties from a file and annotated classes for the entity models.
public abstract class BaseHibernateItemReader<T, S extends HibernateProperties>
    extends JpaCursorItemReader<T> {

  [...]

  protected void setQueryProvider(String databaseName) throws ActaporterConfigurationException {
    Properties properties =
        this.adapterConfigurationProperties.getHibernateProperties(databaseName);

    // create hibernate configuration by aggregating properties from a file and annotated classes for the entity models
    HibernateConfig configuration = new HibernateConfig();
    configuration.addProperties(properties);
    configuration.scanPackages(
        (String) properties.get(HibernateProperties.PROPERTY_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN));

    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();

    setEntityManagerFactory(sessionFactory);

    CriteriaBuilder builder = sessionFactory.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<T> query = builder.createQuery(this.entityClass);
    Root<T> root = query.from(this.entityClass);
    query.select(root);

    // add custom where clause
    Predicate[] p = getWhereClause(builder, root);
    if (p != null) {
      query.where(p);
    }

    // add custom order
    List<Order> o = getOrderBy(builder, root);
    if (o != null) {
      query.orderBy(o);
    }

    // set QueryProvider to JpaCursorItemReader
    setQueryProvider(new JpaCriteriaQueryProvider<>(query));
  }

  [...]

}

class JpaCriteriaQueryProvider<T> extends AbstractJpaQueryProvider {
  private final CriteriaQuery<T> query;

  public JpaCriteriaQueryProvider(CriteriaQuery<T> query) {
    this.query = query;
  }

  @Override
  public Query createQuery() {
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(this.query);
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() {}
}


Please post more information like the actual configuration of the reader etc.

@M.Deinum Thank you for your quick reply. I've added a code snippet of my reader class. Please let me know if you need more information.

If you are using Spring Boot then why are you configuring Hibernate y ourself isntead of using the Spring Boot created one? With thisyou are working around Spring and Spring Boot.

@M.Deinum Thank you for your reply. I assume you suggest creating the hibernate config like this.
We're building the hibernate configuration manually, because the connection strings for the database are written in a properties file.
Do you think the behaviour of the IteamReader might be linked to the way, our hibernate config is built?

It certainly is part of it, as Spring doesn't know about it it cannot manage the transactions surrounding it and you are basically at the whims of Hibernate. What makes you think Spring cannot read and use properties file? What do you think the application.properties is?
